# Import into macOS 10.15 Catalina's Apple Music does not work: unknown error -54; likely root cause: file access permissions

Tags: macos, permission, apple-music, catalina, import

Something is wrong with my version of Apple Music following an upgrade to macOS 10.15 Catalina. Importing songs fails with error "Copying files failed. An unknown error occured (-54)".

The problem goes away if I choose Preferences / Files / Copy Files to Music Media folder when adding to library: No, but resurfaces when I then choose File / Library / Organize Library / Consolidate files.

So this looks clearly like an issue in relation to file access permissions. I did't change from the defaults, and e.g. my `Music/iTunes` has "Read & Write" only for "Me", which seems readanable.

Is this a known issue (apparently not known to Google in this particular incarnation at this point) and how can it be remedied? I prefer a "conservative" solution in terms of granting additional access rights.

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure removed the problem:

1. In Finder, select `/Users/myaccount/Music/iTunes`, the "Get Info".
2. Current permissions are `me: Read & Write`, `system: Read & Write`, `wheel: Read only`, `everyone: Read only`. (I apparently mad a mistake in the earlier observation that only `me` had `Read & Write` permission there.)
3. Select "Apply to enclosed items".